# Android: Calculate Task Graph Error

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I appear to be getting this Gradle error after updating a project:

```
Configuration on demand is not supported by the current version of the Android Gradle plugin since you are using Gradle version 4.6 or above. Suggestion: disable configuration on demand by setting org.gradle.configureondemand=false in your gradle.properties file or use a Gradle version less than 4.6.
```

When the tab is opened up for further examination it appears as below:

```
org.gradle.api.ProjectConfigurationException: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
Caused by: org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.PluginApplicationException: Failed to apply plugin [id 'com.android.application']
Caused by: org.gradle.api.tasks.StopExecutionException: Configuration on demand is not supported by the current version of the Android Gradle plugin since you are using Gradle version 4.6 or above. Suggestion: disable configuration on demand by setting org.gradle.configureondemand=false in your gradle.properties file or use a Gradle version less than 4.6.
```

I have tried the 2 suggestions that it has separately and together to no avail. Please see my Gradle files below.

Gradle Project File

```
buildscript {
ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.50'
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    classpath "io.realm:realm-gradle-plugin:5.0.0"
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.0'




    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
}
}
task clean(type: Delete) {
delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Gradle Module File

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

apply plugin: 'realm-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
android {
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.blah.blah"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        postprocessing {
            removeUnusedCode false
            removeUnusedResources false
            obfuscate false
            optimizeCode false
            proguardFile 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}}
dependencies {
implementation 'com.stripe:stripe-android:6.1.2'
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
implementation "cz.msebera.android:httpclient:4.4.1.2"

implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation  'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation files('libs/stripe-java-5.23.1.jar')
implementation  'com.android.volley:volley:1.0.0'
implementation  'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Gradle Properties Files

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
#org.gradle.parallel=true
```

I'm hoping someone can enlighten me. I will upload more file data if you need it.

Comment: in your gradle properties file add `org.gradle.configureondemand=false`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the error. You need to

> Configuration on demand is not supported by the current version of the
>   Android Gradle plugin since you are using Gradle version 4.6 or above.
>   Suggestion: disable configuration on demand by setting
>   `org.gradle.configureondemand=false` `in` your `gradle.properties` file or
>   use a Gradle version less than 4.6.

so do

```
# Project-wide Gradle settings.

# IDE (e.g. Android Studio) users:
# Gradle settings configured through the IDE *will override*
# any settings specified in this file.

# For more details on how to configure your build environment visit
# http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/build_environment.html

# Specifies the JVM arguments used for the daemon process.
# The setting is particularly useful for tweaking memory settings.
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx1536m
org.gradle.configureondemand=false

# When configured, Gradle will run in incubating parallel mode.
# This option should only be used with decoupled projects. More details, visit
#org.gradle.parallel=true
```

Note: There's also an option in IDE "Configure on demand"(search in search tool, you will find it under "compiler" option) uncheck that option and adding "org.gradle.configureondemand=false" in global gradle properties file which is usually in C drive(windows) or in your OS partition(MAC or linux) and don't forget to enable hidden files (windows-> view options and Mac command+shift+.)

Find more at

[configuration on demand in Gradle](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:configuration_on_demand)

[what exactly is “configuration on demand” in Gradle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740440/what-exactly-is-configuration-on-demand-in-gradle)

---

or you can also downgrade your gradle version.

Goto `Project->Gradle->wrapper` and open `gradle-wrapper.properties` file

and change the value of `distributionUrl` as

```
distributionUrl = https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip
```

[Supported gradle versions in android](https://developer.android.com/studio/releases/gradle-plugin#updating-gradle)

Comment: you might need to change `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'` to `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'`

Comment: I tried all three of the above methods and the only one that worked is downgrading Gradle. Thank you for your help. Note: Using "org.gradle.configureondemand=false" did not work for some reason. It just gave the same error.

Comment: actually there are couple of other place which has this option enabled , in studio and in global gradle properties files as well

Answer (score 1):

Click **File** on Android Studio Menu List, and choose **Invalidate Caches**, and then it will show you a dialog, Click the **Invalidate and Restart**. It works for me. Additionally, I have set **org.gradle.configureondemand=false in your gradle.properties** as Pavneet_Singh said above before invalidating caches.