# Gradle task is not found, but exist in tasks list

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I want to create a custom gradle task for an Android project, that will call chain of other tasks depends on build flavor and build configuration.

So, that what I do in my build.gradle.kts (we use kotlin script)

```kotlin
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    rootProject.allprojects.filter { project ->
        !Config.CodeQuality.ignoredProjects.contains(project.name)
    }.forEach { project ->
        project.tasks.filter { task ->
            task.name.startsWith("lint")
        }.forEach { task ->
            val taskSyfix = task.name.drop(4)
            val taskName = "codeQuality$taskSyfix"
            println("qualityscripts create task $taskName")
            project.tasks.create(taskName) {
                group = "verification"
                dependsOn("checkstyle", "deteltCkeck", "ktlint", task.name)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So than if I run ./gradlew tasks

```
...
Verification tasks
------------------ 
check - Runs all checks. checkstyle - Runs checkstyle. 
codeQuality 
codeQualityDebug 
codeQualityDevMenuFlavor1Debug
codeQualityDevMenuFlavor1Release 
codeQualityDevMenuFlavor2Debug
codeQualityDevMenuFlavor2Release 
...
```

So they exist. But then, if I try to run any, I got next error:

> - What went wrong: Task 'codeQualityDevMenuFlavor1Debug' not found in root project 'myproject-android'.

Comment: if these tasks are created on the sub-project (e.g. subproject `app`), you need to provide full task path: `./gradlew  :app:codeQualityDevMenuFlavor1Debug`

Comment: If I run in this way, I got the same problem. 
I think that problem in lifecycle - gradle try call task before it was added, but some examples that I saw used similar approach

Comment: did you find some time to retest after disabling Configuration on Demand? I'm curious to know if this solved your issue.

Answer (score 3):

I could reproduce your problem and I think it's connected to the **Configuration on demand** execution mode, which seems to be enabled in your environment. Could you try to disable this mode and retest?  ( in Android Studio: `File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler` : uncheck the "configure on demand" option).

It looks like when this mode is enabled, and when you try to execute a task which has been dynamically created (e.g.: your `codeQuality`* tasks):  Gradle will not execute the `gradle.projectsEvaluated {}` block : so in your case your custom tasks will not be created , causing the error `Task 'codeQualityDevMenuFlavor1Debug' not found`

See [Configuration on demand](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:configuration_on_demand) and also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39740440/what-exactly-is-configuration-on-demand-in-gradle) for more information about the *Configuration on demand* feature.

There are also some known issues with Android Studio and this mode, see : [Configuration on demand is not supported by the current version of the Android Gradle plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49990933/configuration-on-demand-is-not-supported-by-the-current-version-of-the-android-g)